# SQLSTATE[23000]: foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Hi I still receives this error, but everything looks good, and migrations work correctly.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`fakturytable`.`fakturas`, CONSTRAINT
>   `fakturas_id_sprzedawcy_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sprzedawcy`)
>   REFERENCES `sprzedawcas` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into
>   `fakturas` (`typ_faktury`, `data_wystawienia`, `mejsce_wystawienia`,
>   `data_sprzedazy`, `towar_usluga`, `jm`, `ilosc`, `cena_netto`,
>   `watosc_netto`, `stawka_vat`, `kwota_vat`, `wartosc_brutto`, `status`,
>   `sposob_platnosci`, `numer_konta`, `termin_platnosci`) values
>   (fsturaVAT, 2020.10.14, Minsk Mazowiecki, 2020.10.26, porty, jan, 10,
>   23456, 421124, 1234, 207, 1107, nieaplacona, qwrq,
>   12345678901234567890098321, 2020.10.28))

fakturas migration:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFakturasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('fakturas', function(Blueprint $table){      
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedinteger('id_sprzedawcy');
            $table->unsignedinteger('id_nabywcy');
            $table->string('typ_faktury');
            $table->date('data_wystawienia');
            $table->string('mejsce_wystawienia');
            $table->date('data_sprzedazy');
            $table->string('towar_usluga');
            $table->string('jm');
            $table->bigInteger('ilosc');
            $table->bigInteger('cena_netto');
            $table->bigInteger('watosc_netto');
            $table->bigInteger('stawka_vat');
            $table->bigInteger('kwota_vat');
            $table->bigInteger('wartosc_brutto');
            $table->string('status');
            $table->string('sposob_platnosci');
            $table->string('numer_konta');
            $table->date('termin_platnosci');


        });
        Schema::table('fakturas',function($table){
            $table->foreign('id_sprzedawcy')
            ->references('id')->on('sprzedawcas')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('id_nabywcy')
            ->references('id')->on('nabywcas')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }
    public function down()
    {

       Schema::dropIfExists('fakturas');
       Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi you have to put same data type which at parent table id like `  $table->unsignedinteger('id_sprzedawcy');` I think here is `  $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_sprzedawcy');`

Comment: I use a increments in id in table  nabywcas

Comment: what is data type of `id` in this table `sprzedawcas`?

Comment: increments on id

Comment: I am saying what is the datatype of your `id` attribute in this table `sprzedawcas` or post your this table too in your question.

Comment: looks like you're trying to insert a value in "id_sprzedawcy" that does not exist in "sprzedawcas.id" -- though you're not defining "id_sprzedawcy" in your insert statement. What is is your "sprzedawcas" table? Is it empty?

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sprzedawcas', function(Blueprint $table){
            
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('sprzedawca');
            $table->string('nip_sprzedawca');
            $table->string('ulica_sprzedawca');
            $table->string('miasto_spzedawca');
            $table->string('kod_pocztowy_sprzedawca');


        });
  
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your insert is incorrect.

```sql
insert into fakturas (typ_faktury, data_wystawienia, mejsce_wystawienia, data_sprzedazy, towar_usluga, jm, ilosc, cena_netto, watosc_netto, stawka_vat, kwota_vat, wartosc_brutto, status, sposob_platnosci, numer_konta, termin_platnosci) values (fsturaVAT, 2020.10.14, Minsk Mazowiecki, 2020.10.26, porty, jan, 10, 23456, 421124, 1234, 207, 1107, nieaplacona, qwrq, 12345678901234567890098321, 2020.10.28))
```

does not reference `id_sprzedawcy`, which you have made a requirement in your migration. (the foreign key).

You need to provide a valid `id_sprzedawcy` in your insert, or remove the foreign key constraint.

Comment: yea but need on this one fogein key

Comment: If you need it, you need to include a value for it in your insert. You cannot insert a row that has a foreign key without providing the foreign key value.

Comment: Wherever you are doing this insert into `fakturas` you need to add in `id_sprzedawcy` with a valid ID from the table `sprzedawcas`. I cannot explain this any further.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide value of id_sprzedawcy (which should be an id that exists in sprzedawcas table) while inserting .
either provide it in the create statement or make it nullable in migration :

```
$table->unsignedinteger('id_sprzedawcy')->nullable();
```

the same applies to any other foreign keys you have.

Comment: yea but i have got there autoincrements

Comment: the id_sprzedawcy is a separate column from the id column in sprzedawcas, it just references it, but you have to supply a value for it.
this value is from the id column in sprzedawcas.
the id_sprzedawcy column in fakturas  table is not  id column in sprzedawcas table   it just references it,  when you insert a value of 1 in the id_sprzedawcy column in fakturas , it just means : hey you're looking for the sprzedawcy , go to the sprzedawcas table and look for the row that has the id : 1

Comment: can you post your create statement ?